# "Variable set but not used" error - How to solve?

Tags: c

I get this error, the error is just not for 'stringsix" but for all the declared variables :

```
assignment42.c:22:9: warning: variable ‘stringSix’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
```

I just want to pass it from main to functions. I face this problem many times, could someone please tell me an easy to avoid this problem.

```
int main()
{
char ** listofdetails;
char ** stringOne;
char ** stringTwo;
char ** stringThree;
char ** stringFour;
char ** stringFive;
char ** stringSix;

listofdetails = lineParse();    
printf("%s \n", listofdetails[2]);
stringOne = seperateString1(listofdetails);
stringTwo = seperateString2(listofdetails);
stringThree = seperateString3(listofdetails);
stringFour = seperateString4(listofdetails);
stringFive = seperateString5(listofdetails);
stringSix = seperateString6(listofdetails);
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're setting those variables and not using them. If you intend to do something with the value stored in `stringOne`, you should so do.

Comment: Note that it's not en error, just a warning.

Answer (score 11):

First of all it's not an error, it's a *warning*. Many warnings can be signs of you doing something you should not do (and maybe even cause [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)), but they are not things that will stop the build-process.

As for that specific warning, it's just what it says, you are setting (initializing/assigning to) a variable, but you don't use the variable.

There are two obvious things you could do to not get the warning: Don't do the assignment, or use the variable in an expression.

Answer (score 10):

```
(void)stringSix;
```

can silence this warning, but this is a bad solution, you should care about warnings.

Comment: There are some situations, like auto-generated code, where it's awkward to avoid creating variables that won't be used. The general admonition that code should be succinct and readable doesn't necessarily apply in these situations and the above is a good solution.